# How Can I Trace the Origin of Outbound Spam Mail in Mavericks Server?

Tags: macos, email, osx-server, spam, smtp

My Mavericks Server mail server has been compromised and has been sending reams of Nigerian royalty scam emails out. Where can I find log files which will enable me to track down the IP address these messages originated from (in case their is a machine with an infection on my network) and which credentials are being used to authenticate to the SMTP server?

Comment: in Mail use the "All header" to see that information.

Comment: I'm not receiving the mail, I'm unwittingly relaying it. In a server like Kerio Connect, I could use the logging features to  tell me where the spam was coming from and whose credentials had been compromised. The Server apps Mail and SMTP logs don't seem to record sender ID and IP for each message going through the queue.

Comment: I think I'm looking for a Postfix access or security log but I don't know where it's kept or if OS X even uses them in its version of Postfix.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find that Information in `/var/log/Mail.log` and some more in `/var/log/system.log`.